# Salesforce Visualforce Email not tracking even with HTML body

Tags: visualforce, community, html

I have a custom button in an opportunity that sends an visualforce email with an attached quote to the client.  I have everything working, ie the email is sent, the quote pdf is saved to the account, and the email is recorded under the account activity. The only thing not working is that I would like to track this email with the built in HTML email status.  I do have email tracking enabled and all my html email templates track properly.

The code in the visualforce email template is

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!relatedTo.Account.name} your estimate from Company Name has arrived!" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <c:EstimateEmailComponent oppId="{!relatedTo.id}"></c:EstimateEmailComponent>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

This is then populated in an Apex Component Class with fields from the opportunity.

From my understanding, having html in the template should result in the email being tracked.  Except it does not appear under the HTML Email Status list.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome Scorer54! Are you the user who is generating the actual email?

Comment: I am.  I add the products/info to a opportunity myself, and then when ready click on the custom button to send the email with attached quote.